# stdout all at once instead of line by line

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a script that gets load and mem information for a list of servers by ssh'ing to each server. However, since there are around 20 servers, it's not very efficient to wait for the script to end. That's why I thought it might be interesting to make a crontab that writes the output of the script to a file, so all I need to do is cat this file whenever I need to know load and mem information for the 20 servers. However, when I cat this file during the execution of the crontab it will give me incomplete information. That's because the output of my script is written line by line to the file instead of all at once at termination. I wonder what needs to be done to make this work...

My crontab:

```
* * * * * (date;~/bin/RUP_ssh) &> ~/bin/RUP.out
```

My bash script (RUP_ssh):

```
for comp in `cat ~/bin/servers`; do
    ssh $comp ~/bin/ca
done
```

Thanks,

niefpaarschoenen

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Parallel ssh (pssh)](http://www.theether.org/pssh/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buffer the output to a temporary file and then output all at once like this:

```
outputbuffer=`mktemp` # Create a new temporary file, usually in /tmp/
trap "rm '$outputbuffer'" EXIT # Remove the temporary file if we exit early.
for comp in `cat ~/bin/servers`; do
    ssh $comp ~/bin/ca >> "$outputbuffer" # gather info to buffer file
done
cat "$outputbuffer" # print buffer to stdout
# rm "$outputbuffer" # delete temporary file, not necessary when using trap
```

Comment: You need to use `>>`, otherwise each ssh command will overwrite the temp file. Or move the output redirection to after `done`.

Comment: Tidier still, `trap "rm '$outputbuffer'" EXIT`.

Comment: Buffering to a file is a good idea and an easy solution, thanks. However, I don't like the fact that this is put in the script, because these additions only make sense for the crontab: when you run the script by itself you want the output to appear as fast as possible i.e. line by line. So I used your idea and put it in the crontab instead.

Comment: Are there any solutions that don't need a file for buffering? This seems more elegant to me...

Comment: By modifying it a bit you could replace the `> "$outputbuffer"` with the `tee -a "$outputbuffer"` command to both append to the buffer file and show it on stdout, this would require that you replace `cat "$outputbuffer"` with `cp "$outputbuffer" ~/bin/RUP.out` and pipe the crontab stdout to `/dev/null`.

Comment: (That should have been `| tee -a "$outputbuffer"` of course.)

Comment: One possibility without using temporary files might be to have the `cron` entry be `(date;~/bin/RUP_ssh) | dd of=~/bin/RUP.out bs=1m` where the `1m` block size is chosen to be bigger than the output is ever expected to be. `dd` will try to fill the output block before writing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a string to identify which host the mem/load data has come from you can update your txt file as each result comes in. Asuming the data block is one line long you could use

```
for comp in `cat ~/bin/servers`; do
    output=$( ssh $comp ~/bin/ca )
    # remove old mem/load data for $comp from RUP.out
    sed -i '/'"$comp"'/d' RUP.out # this assumes that the string "$comp" is
                                  # integrated into the output from ca, and
                                  # not elsewhere
    echo "$output" >> RUP.out
done
```

This can be adapted depending on the output of ca. There is lots of help on sed across the net.